# UIWebView - load url with custom content-type

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my app I'm using a web view (a simple UIWebView) to display a web page that lists some files.
For some reason, the server (which is not in my control) wants to force the user to download the file, and as far as I can see, it does it in 2 ways - (a) setting Content-Disposition: attachment; in the header and (b) changing the content type to be Content-Type: application/x-forcedownload.

The web view will display the known 'Frame load interrupted' error when trying to open one of these files inside the web view, and if accessing the same page in the phone's native Safari app and clicking one of those files, it will display a different error saying 'Download Failed - Safari cannot download this file'.

It seems to me that the reason for these errors is that the content type was changed, though the file is a regular, simple, PDF file.

So, if only I could tell my web view the right content-type (or even to ignore it, as the file's extension is .pdf), I believe it will happily display the file.

Do you how can that be accomplished?

Thanks a bunch,

Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I used UIWebViewDelegate to recognise requests to such files, download the content of the file in the background and display it with `[webView loadData:self.webdata MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil]`;

That's the code that does the job (self.webdata is an NSMutableData property of the class).

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)_webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    // If the link is about to use a weird Content-Type, stop the UIWebView request
    //    and get the data through a NSUrlConnection
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString hasSuffix:@"forcedownload=1"])
    {
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        // Show an activity indicator
        [self showActivityIndicators];
        return NO;
    }

    return [super webView:_webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    self.webdata = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.webdata appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [self hideActivityIndicators];

    // Loads an empty URL to give the user the "Back" button ability
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
    // Load the content
    [webView loadData:self.webdata MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
}
```